# I'm trying to build D3.js by using CodeMirror editor, but anything I input in there can't be properly visualized by D3.js. What am I missing?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts, visualization, codemirror

I'm new to D3.js and CodeMirror (and to StackOverflow as well, please pardon my mistakes) and I want to try some cool stuff for my newest project, so these two are my best bet but I had some problem. Please help me noticing what I'm doing wrong, and what the best solution to make this program work out. I'm glad we have good forum here.

So, long story short, I'm trying to build a visualization tools by using D3.js and CodeMirror as my editor. For example, [this](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4061502) is what I try to visualize, but instead of reading the `morley.csv` data ([hard-coded](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4061502#morley.csv)), I want to input the data from my CodeMirror editor. So this is what I write for the editor:

```
<textarea id="values"></textarea>

<script>
  var editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(values, {
    lineNumbers: true,
    matchBrackets: true,
    theme : '3024-day'
  });
</script>

<a id="gen" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" role="button">Generate Visualization</a>
```

And this for the visualization builder:

```
<div class="row" id="chart">
  <script>
    d3.select("#gen").on("click", function(){
      d3.event.preventDefault(); 
      d3.select("#chart svg").remove();
      var dataset = editor.getValue();

      var margin = {top: 10, right: 50, bottom: 20, left: 50},
      width = 120 - margin.left - margin.right,
      height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

      var min = Infinity,
      max = -Infinity;

      var chart = d3.box()
      .whiskers(iqr(1.5))
      .width(width)
      .height(height);

      d3.csv(dataset, function(error, csv) {
        if (error) throw error;

        var data = [];

        csv.forEach(function(x) {
        var e = Math.floor(x.Expt - 1),
        r = Math.floor(x.Run - 1),
        s = Math.floor(x.Speed),
        d = data[e];
        if (!d) d = data[e] = [s];
        else d.push(s);
        if (s > max) max = s;
        if (s < min) min = s;
        });

        chart.domain([min, max]);

        var svg = d3.select("#chart").selectAll("svg")
        .data(data)
        .enter().append("svg")
        .attr("class", "box")
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.bottom + margin.top)
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")
        .call(chart);

        setInterval(function() {
        svg.datum(randomize).call(chart.duration(1000));
        }, 2000); 
      });

      function randomize(d) {
        if (!d.randomizer) d.randomizer = randomizer(d);
        return d.map(d.randomizer);
      }

      function randomizer(d) {
        var k = d3.max(d) * .02;
        return function(d) {
        return Math.max(min, Math.min(max, d + k * (Math.random() - .5)));
        };
      }

      function iqr(k) {
        return function(d, i) {
          var q1 = d.quartiles[0],
          q3 = d.quartiles[2],
          iqr = (q3 - q1) * k,
          i = -1,
          j = d.length;
          while (d[++i] < q1 - iqr);
          while (d[--j] > q3 + iqr);
          return [i, j];
        };
      }
    });
  </script>
</div>
```

Let's just assumed I used the same `morley.csv` for my input data.

Somehow it didn't work as I planned. I don't understand what I'm missing here, but my best guess it must have something to do with how `d3.csv` can't parse my input from `textarea values`. The output `div chart` is always show nothing..

Thanks for helping out, although I'm new here. Any help is more than appreciated.

Comment: I think you are on the right path to try to get it working with a csv file first, so at least you have something that you can then start tweaking.  Honestly, I would put some console logging just before this line:  if (error) throw error;  See what the values of csv and error are.

Comment: @spozun Thanks for the fast response. So I did what you suggest me to do, and I got 2 errors from my console: **(1) "Failed to load resource [..] 403 (Forbidden)**; somehow the data is inserted to my link (localhost/myweb/Expt,Run,Speed1,1,..), and **(2) Uncaught [object XMLHttpRequest]**. Can you help enlighten me, why this can be happen?

Comment: Check out my answer below, I think you just need to change to the parse() function since you are sending in a string of data and not really a file.  It's trying to append a file path since it thinks you are trying to load a file.  @NamiraZahra

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.
Change `d3.csv()` to `d3.csv.parse()` or `d3.csvParse()` in the newer versions.  The former only accepts a file name, the latter accepts a string of CSV data.

Debug and make sure your dataset variable is truly a comma separated string.

2.
Also, if all that you need is a flat array like [1,2,3], I think you need to take all of that code out of the callback function and just do this:

```
data = d3.csv.parse(dataset);
```

Then just continue with your existing code after that.

The reason to have a callback function in the csv.parse call is only to structure the returned array; e.g. if your array elements are objects with multiple values inside of them, you'd set that up in the callback function.

Comment: It actually helps a bit, but it looks like I'm still oblivious to something. The "Failed to load [..]" error now is solved, but unfortunately the "Uncaught [object Object]" is still there, so the visualization is not yet shown in my `div chart`.

Comment: @NamiraZahra I just updated my answer with the other piece you need.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! I'll try to implement the code later, then I'll give an update when I get any progress.

Comment: Okay, I almost completely forgotten about this, I'm very sorry about that. Just to clarify, **@Spozun's suggestion to take all of my code out from the callback function and implement** `data = d3.csv.parse(dataset);` **is work flawlessly for me**. That was a big help, thank you very much. To appreciate this, I'll gladly put your name in my credit list. Cheers! :)